# very confused with passing data array from controller to view in laravel or calling it from the view

Tags: php, laravel-5, builder

ok I have my route to my controller (for future crud maybe angular use)

```
public function Dashboard_Clicks()
{
    $DBClicks = DB::table('TotalClicks')->select('Total_Clicks')->get();


return view::('dashboard.pages')->with('$DBClicks', Total_Clicks);
```

do I use view composer? or another clean simple way to call this in?
    }

this has one result a number 45454

I want to be able to get this result in my view like so.

```
<h1 class="clicks"><strong>{{ $DBClicks->Total_Clicks }} </strong> </h1>
```

Comment: if you want to use the same thing in all pages then you can use composer view . see here http://culttt.com/2014/02/10/using-view-composers-laravel-4/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: (Laravel 5)

```
return view('dashboard.pages', ['Total_Clicks' => $DBClicks]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can recall there are two ways of passing data from controller to views first is compacting the variable in your controller and it will available as it is in your view. An example for the same is following:

```
$variable = 'somedata';
$array = ['some' => 'data'];

return view('viewName', compact('variable', 'array'));
//now in your view you can access {{$variable}} and @foreach($array as $something)
```

Second is with :

```
return view('viewName')->with(['first_var' => $variable, 'first_array' => $array])
//now in your view you can access {{$first_var}} and @foreach($first_array as $array)
```